# How can I properly overload the << operator for an ostream?

Tags: c++, namespaces, operator-overloading, iostream, ostream

I am writing a small matrix library in C++ for matrix operations. However, my compiler complains, where before it did not. This code was left on a shelf for six months and in between I upgraded my computer from [Debian 4.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_version_history#Debian_4.0_(Etch)) (Etch) to [Debian 5.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian_version_history#Debian_5.0_(Lenny)) (Lenny) (g++ (Debian 4.3.2-1.1) 4.3.2). However, I have the same problem on a [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29) system with the same g++.

Here is the relevant part of my matrix class:

```
namespace Math
{
    class Matrix
    {
    public:

        [...]

        friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& stream, const Matrix& matrix);
    }
}
```

And the "implementation":

```
using namespace Math;

std::ostream& Matrix::operator <<(std::ostream& stream, const Matrix& matrix) {

    [...]

}
```

This is the error given by the compiler:

> matrix.cpp:459: error: 'std::ostream&
> Math::Matrix::operator<<(std::ostream&,
> const Math::Matrix&)' must take
> exactly one argument

I'm a bit confused by this error, but then again my C++ has gotten a bit rusty after doing lots of Java those six months. :-)

Answer (score 145, accepted):

You have declared your function as `friend`. It's not a member of the class. You should remove `Matrix::` from the implementation. `friend` means that the specified function (which is not a member of the class) can access private member variables. The way you implemented the function is like an instance method for `Matrix` class which is wrong.

Comment: And you should also declare it inside the Math namespace (not just with an using namespace Math).

Comment: Why does the `operator<<` have to be in the namespace of `Math`? It seems that it should be in the global namespace. I agree that my compiler wants it to be in the namespace of `Math`, but that doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Sorry, but I fail to see why do we use friend keyword here then? When declare friend operator override in a class, it seems like we cannot implement with Matrix::operator<<(ostream& os, const Matrix& m). Instead we need to just use global operator override operator<<ostream& os, const Matrix& m) so why even bother to declare it inside class in the first place?

Comment: Patrick, You would use `friend` so that the implementation has access to private (and protected) member variables. E.g. It's likely you would want to print all the elements of the matrix, which may be private.

Answer (score 158):

I am just telling you about one other possibility: I like using friend definitions for that:

```
namespace Math
{
    class Matrix
    {
    public:

        [...]

        friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& stream, const Matrix& matrix) {
            [...]
        }
    };
}
```

The function will be automatically targeted into the surrounding namespace `Math` (even though its definition appears within the scope of that class) but will not be visible unless you call operator<< with a Matrix object which will make argument dependent lookup find that operator definition. That can sometimes help with ambiguous calls, since it's invisible for argument types other than Matrix. When writing its definition, you can also refer directly to names defined in Matrix and to Matrix itself, without qualifying the name with some possibly long prefix and providing template parameters like `Math::Matrix<TypeA, N>`.

Answer (score 94):

To add to [Mehrdad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476272/how-can-i-properly-overload-the-operator-for-an-ostream/476279#476279),

```
namespace Math
{
    class Matrix
    {
       public:

       [...]


    }
    std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& stream, const Math::Matrix& matrix);
}
```

In your implementation

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream,
                     const Math::Matrix& matrix) {
    matrix.print(stream); // Assuming you define print for matrix
    return stream;
 }
```

Comment: I don't understand why is this a down vote, this clarifies that you can declare operator to be in the namespace and not even as a friend and how you can possibly declare the operator.

Comment: Mehrdad answer did not have any snippet of code so I just added what might work by moving it outside the class in the namespace itself.

Comment: I understand your point, I only looked at your second snippet. But now I see you took the operator out of the class. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Not only it is out of the class, but it is properly defined _inside_ the Math namespace. Also it has the added advantage (maybe not for a Matrix, but with other classes) that 'print' can be virtual and thus printing will happen at the most derived level of inheritance.

Answer (score 80):

Assuming that we're talking about overloading `operator <<` for all classes derived from `std::ostream` to handle the `Matrix` class (and not overloading `<<` for `Matrix` class), it makes more sense to declare the overload function outside the Math namespace in the header.

Use a friend function only if the functionality cannot be achieved via the public interfaces.

**Matrix.h**

```
namespace Math { 
    class Matrix { 
        //...
    };  
}
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Math::Matrix&);
```

Note that the operator overload is declared outside the namespace.

**Matrix.cpp**

```
using namespace Math;
using namespace std;

ostream& operator<< (ostream& os, const Matrix& obj) {
    os << obj.getXYZ() << obj.getABC() << '\n';
    return os;
}
```

On the other hand, if your overload function *does* need to be made a friend i.e. needs access to private and protected members.

**Math.h**

```
namespace Math {
    class Matrix {
        public:
            friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Matrix&);
    };
}
```

You need to enclose the function definition with a namespace block instead of just `using namespace Math;`.

**Matrix.cpp**

```
using namespace Math;
using namespace std;

namespace Math {
    ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Matrix& obj) {
        os << obj.XYZ << obj.ABC << '\n';
        return os;
    }                 
}
```

Comment: Just a little nitpicking here.. i find `os` to be a poor abbreviation in this case (it is bound too much to "operating system")

Comment: Can the `operator<<` overload be put (declared and implemented) inside the class, and we don't talk about friendship?

Answer (score 49):

In [C++14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B14), you can use the following template to print any object which has a  T::print(std::ostream&)const; member.

```
template<class T>
auto operator<<(std::ostream& os, T const & t) -> decltype(t.print(os), os)
{
    t.print(os);
    return os;
}
```

In [C++20](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B20), [concepts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concepts_(C%2B%2B)) can be used.

```
template<typename T>
concept Printable = requires(std::ostream& os, T const & t) {
    { t.print(os) };
};

template<Printable T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const T& t) {
    t.print(os);
    return os;
}
```

Comment: interesting solution! One question - where this operator should  be declared, like in a global scope? I assume it should be visible to all types which can be used to templatize it?

Comment: @barney It could be in your own namespace along with the classes that use it.

Comment: can't you just return `std::ostream&`, since it's the return type anyway ?

Comment: @Jean-MichaëlCelerier The decltype makes sure that this operator is only used when t::print is present. Otherwise it would attempt to compile the function body and give a compilation error.

Comment: Concepts version added, tested here https://godbolt.org/z/u9fGbK

Answer (score 4):

I would like to simplify this a little with an example that overloads `<<` to print an array.

1. First pass both the object types around the `<<` operator
2. Create a function to overload the operator as follows.

   ```cpp
   #include <iostream>
   using namespace std;

   void operator<<(ostream& os, int arr[]) {
       for (int i = 0;i < 10; i++) {
           os << arr[i] << " ";
       }
       os << endl;
   }

   int main() {
       int arr[10] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
       cout << arr;
   }
   ```

If cascading of operators is also required, make sure to return a `cout` object
in the overloaded function as follows,

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, int arr[]) {
    for (int i = 0;i < 10; i++) {
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    return os;
}

int main() {
    int arr[10] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    int arr2[10] = { 11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77, 88, 99, 100 };
    // Cascading of operators
    cout << arr << arr2;
}
```

Comment: You can make it work with any size array:- `template<int N> ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, int(& arr)[N]) { etc`

Comment: Shouldn't be `os` instead of `cout` inside the `operator==` function?