# C++ How to iterate through a std::vector of objects and show content on console

Tags: c++, stdvector

For loop should iterate through std::vector and populate content.

First for loop gives me an error message saying:

NO BINARY OPERATOR FOUND << No convert possible

```
vector<MyClass>classVector;
    for (vector<MyClass>::iterator i = classVector.begin();
                           i != classVector.end();
                           ++i)
            {
                cout << *i << endl;
            }
```

MyClass.h:

```
class MyClass{

private:

    string newTodayTaskString;

public:
    MyClass(string t) : newTodayTaskString (t){}

    ~MyClass(){}
};
```

This for loop iterates through a vector of strings and works perfectly. Why?

```
vector<string>stringVector;
   for (vector<string>::iterator i = stringVector.begin(); 
                         i != stringVector.end(); 
                         ++i) 
            {
                cout<<*i<<endl;
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to overload the stream operator for your class if you want to be able to directly call `std::cout::operator <<`.

You can either define it as:

```
 std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& stream, const MyClass& obj)
 {
    stream << obj.newTodayTaskString;
 }
```

and declare this operator as friend so it has access to the private members of the class or provide a print function to your class and use that instead.

Answer (score 5):

The question is unrelated to iteration, it's just because you can write

```
std::string s = "Hello";
std::cout << s;
```

but not

```
MyClass o("Hello");
std::cout << o;
```

See [How to properly overload the << operator for an ostream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476272/how-to-properly-overload-the-operator-for-an-ostream) on how to overload `operator <<` to make it work!

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to print a member of the class, not the class itself.

For example:

```
cout << (*i).Name << endl;
```

Comment: Correct, sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 1):

you are iterating through the vector of "MyClass", which is perhaps a user-defined type.So you must tell the compiler, in which data of "MyClass" class you are interested in.
Below is a sample code- just for understanding purpose

```
// Temp_Practice.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<memory>
#include<ostream>
#include <vector>>
using namespace std;

// This example is just for understanding/Demo purpose.
// it will not run on any compiler
class MyClass {
public:
    std::string _name;
    std::string _address;
    int         _age;
    // Constructor
public:
    MyClass() {}
    MyClass(std::string name, std::string address, int age) :_name(name), _address(address), _age(age) {}

    //Destructor
    //..

    // other stuff
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& os, std::string _input);

};
 ostream& operator << (ostream& os, std::string _input)
{
     os << _input.c_str();
     return os;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<MyClass> vecMyClass;

    MyClass temp("AA", "BB", 1);
    vecMyClass.push_back(temp);

    MyClass temp1("CC", "DD", 2);
    vecMyClass.push_back(temp1);

    MyClass temp2("EE", "FF", 3);
    vecMyClass.push_back(temp2);

    MyClass temp3("GG", "HH", 4);
    vecMyClass.push_back(temp3);

    MyClass temp4("II", "JJ", 5);
    vecMyClass.push_back(temp4);

    MyClass temp5("KK", "LL", 6);
    vecMyClass.push_back(temp5);
    std::vector<MyClass>::iterator itr;
    for ( itr = vecMyClass.begin(); itr != vecMyClass.end(); ++itr)
    {
        // Compiler throws error; it does not know what programer wants to print. So its 
        // programer responsiblity to let compiler know what to be printed
         //std::cout << itr << std::endl; //  Error!!!!

        // Correct Code
        std::cout << itr->_name << itr->_address << itr->_age << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should overload output operator.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

class MyClass{

private:
    std::string newTodayTaskString;

public:
    explicit MyClass(const std::string t) : newTodayTaskString (t){}
    std::ostream& print(std::ostream& os) const { return os << newTodayTaskString; }

    ~MyClass(){}
};

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const MyClass& obj)
{
    return obj.print(os);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<MyClass> vec = {MyClass("add"), MyClass("clear")};
    std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::ostream_iterator<MyClass>(std::cout, "\n"));
}
```

Comment: Thank you too for the solution.