# overloading the << and defining a stream manipulator c++

Tags: c++, vector, operator-overloading, manipulators

I am hoping someone could offer some insight on a particular problem im having. I am writing a program that takes in integers, stores them in a vector, and prints them out with comma separators for numbers larger than 999 -> 1,000.

My question is.. well, two actually, how can i pass a vector to a function, and second, if i wanted to overload the << to do all this behind the scenes would that be possible?

global function from a class Comma:

```
template <class T>
string formatWithComma(T value){
    stringstream ss;
    locale commaLoc(locale(), new CommaNumPunc() );
    ss.imbue(commaLoc);
    ss << value;
    return ss.str();
```

loop in main() to display the vector:

```
for (vector<unsigned int>::iterator i = integers.begin(); i != integers.end(); ++i){
    cout << formatWithComma(*i) << "  ";
}
```

Comment: You don't need to write a custom `locale` to have comma separated numbers, `num_punct` should do with `,` as separator and `3` as digit grouping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First question:

> how can i pass a vector to a function

Just pass it directly. For example(assume function template):

```
template <typename T>
void processVector(const vector<T>& vec );
```

Inside main, you can call it as follows:

```
processVector<unsigned int> (integers); //an example instantiation
```

Second question:

> if i wanted to overload the << to do all this behind the scenes would that be possible?

Yes, of course possible. see how to overload `<<` operator from those resources:
[MSDN Overload << operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1z2f6c2k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and 
[Overload the << operator WISC](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~hasti/cs368/CppTutorial/NOTES/OVERLOAD.html)

and a bunch of resource from SO: [How to properly overload << operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476272/how-to-properly-overload-the-operator-for-an-ostream)

Answer (score 2):

Passing a vector to a function can be done like this:

```
void foo(std::vector<T> &vector);
void foo(const std::vector<T> &vector);
```

You typically want to pass by (const) reference to avoid copying the vector.