# C++ compiler has contradictory complaints about overloading the << operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, iostream

By the way, I am using eclipse and g++ on arch linux (I ran pacman -Syu less than a week ago, so everything is up to date).

Eclipse produces an error every time I try to compile this:

```
#ifndef DATE_HPP_
#define DATE_HPP_

using namespace std;

class Date {
public:
    int Year;
    char Month;
    char Day;
    char HH;
    char MM;
    char ss;
    Date();

    /*
     * Overloaded Operator Functions
     */
    //Assignments
    Date operator=(Date input);
    //Comparisons
    bool operator==(Date& rhs);
    bool operator!=(Date& rhs);
    bool operator<(Date& rhs);
    bool operator>(Date& rhs);
    bool operator<=(Date& rhs);
    bool operator>=(Date& rhs);
    //Conversion
    operator char*();
    operator std::string();
    ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Date& date); //TROUBLE LINE
};

#endif /* DATE_HPP_ */
```

Eclipse shows a message on the operator<< declaration saying it must only have a single argument. Yet, when I declare it like this:

```
ostream& operator<<(const Date& date);
```

It complains that it must have two. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/476272/1168156

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two-argument overload of the operator must be a non-member function. Either move it out of the class definition, or add `friend` to it to make it a non-member friend function, whichever makes more sense.

The one-argument overload is not useful, since it is used when the object instance is the left operand.

Comment: So, would you recommend making it part of the header file?

I didn't know there were two ways to overload the function. I've been googling for some good examples of << overloading, but I've yet to find anything that I could get to work. Do you have any links you could share?

Comment: @KG6ZVP: where you put the definition is up to you; only the declaration needs to be in the header. This is one of the most frequently asked questions, though, so I find it hard to believe you couldn't find *any* information.

Comment: The problem wasn't finding any information, it was finding lots of different threads that described doing things that made g++ freak out. I think I've got it sorted now. I left off teaching myself C++ before getting to overloaded operators and I'm pretty rusty on some of the basic syntax.

Answer (score 0):

`friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Date& date);`

Also you can add some consts to your code. For example..

`bool operator==(const Date& rhs) const;`

I also suggest you make all integers int, even if they will only take a small value (such as month) unless there is a technical reason you need them to be chars.

Comment: I was just optimizing for storage space as much as possible, since I will be creating many instances of it (several hundred or more) and they will not be accessed frequently enough for the extra time required to convert to int to matter.

Comment: @KG6ZVP 1000 instances will only save you 14kb.

Comment: @KG6ZVP: Then use `int_least8_t`, which makes your purpose clear.  (year can be `int_least16_t`

Comment: @Neil: That's a big chunk of L1/L2 cache, and even in L3 it is non-trivial.

Comment: @BenVoigt What happened to premature optimization?