# How to overload index operator in C++?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have the following code which declares a class that overloads `operator[]`, as shown here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class BitSet
{
private:
    int size;
public:
    vector<int> set;
    int &operator [] (int index) {
        return set[index];
    }
    BitSet(int nsize = 0)
    {
        cout << "BitSet creating..." << endl;
        size = nsize;
        initSet(size);
    }
    void initSet(int nsize)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < nsize; i++)
        {
            set.push_back(0);
        }
    }
    void setValue(int key, int value)
    {
        set[key] = value;
    }
    int getValue(int key, int value)
    {
        return set[key];
    }

};
```

However, when I try to use it in this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "BitSet.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    BitSet *a;
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    a = new BitSet(10);
    a->setValue(5, 42);
    cout << endl << a[5] << endl; // error here
    return 0;
}
```

I get this error:

> `main.cpp|15|ошибка: no match for «operator<<» in «std::cout.std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator<< [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>::__ostream_type = std::basic_ostream<char>](std::endl [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]) << *(a + 200u)»|`

What's wrong with my implementation of `operator[]`?

Comment: Do you want and ostream operator<< for your Bitset? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476272/how-to-properly-overload-the-operator-for-an-ostream, http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/input_output_operators_overloading.htm

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue has nothing to do with your implementation of `operator[]`.  Notice that you've declared `a` as

```
BitSet *a;
```

Therefore, when you write

```
cout << a[5] << endl;
```

the compiler interprets this as "get element at position five in the array pointed at by `a`, then output it." This isn't what you want, and it causes an error because `BitSet` doesn't define an `operator<<`. (Notice that the actual error you're getting is about `operator<<` in `BitSet` rather than about `operator[]`).

Try changing the line to read

```
cout << (*a)[5] << endl
```

Or, better yet, just declare the `BitSet` without making it a pointer.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, works. And thanks to jxh for fixing my first question here.