# Overloading = operator

Tags: c++

I wrote the following test program:

```
 int main(int argc, char** argv)
   {

    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("D:\\C++\\Assignments\\in1.txt");
    if (!inFile) {
            cout << "Unable to open file";
            exit(1); // terminate with error
    }
    Complex a,b,c;
    inFile >> a;
    inFile >> b;
    ofstream out;
    out.open("D:\\C++\\Assignments\\out1.txt");
    out << a <<endl<< b<<endl;  // dumps data to a stream connected to a file
    out << c=a <<endl;
    out.close();



  return 0;
  }
```

I have overloaded = as following:

```
  void Complex::operator=(const Complex &a)//mulptiplication
  {
    real=a.real;
    imag=a.imag;
   }
```

But I am getting errors like: no match for ooperator <<. Can anyone help with the error?

Comment: Please add the compiler error.

Answer (score 2):

This is your problem:

```
out << c=a <<endl;
```

You need to return a Complex&

Try this:

```
Complex& Complex::operator=(const Complex &a)//mulptiplication
{
  real=a.real;
  imag=a.imag;

  return *this;
}
```

The reason is that c=a yields a void and there is no operator<< that works for void on the left hand side

Just for clarity, you might rewrite as:

```
c = a;
out << c << endl;
```

ortang is also right that there must be an operator<< for the Complex class.

Comment: Thanks @Josh, I tried it but I m getting error that it must be a nonstatic memeber function.

Answer (score 2):

The problem lies in `out << a << endl << b << endl`, since you did not overload the `operator<<` for the `Complex` class i guess.

Take a look at [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476272/how-to-properly-overload-the-operator-for-an-ostream) how to overload the `operator<<`.

Comment: I have defined them in the cpp file. The question is concerning,= operator. However thank you for pointing it out,it is my fault not to post my cpp file.

Answer (score 2):

If `real` and `imag` are themselves of types with correct assign semantics (for example primitive types like `int` or `double`), then it is **redundant and error-prone** to implement your own `operator=`. Just use the compiler-generated one.

Answer (score 2):

Even with proper operators

```
out << c=a <<endl;
```

which is parsed as

```
(out << c) = (a <<endl);
```

the error occurs, due to operator precedence.