# C++: Errors while compilation of C++ program

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am making a class Fraction with global functions usage
My code looks like below:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

ostream & operator<<(ostream & os, Fraction & fr)
{
    return os << fr.get_num() << '/' << fr.get_den();
}

class Fraction
{
private:
    int num, den;
public:
int get_num()
    {
        return num;
    }
    int get_den()
    {
        return den;
    }
};
```

Main function has call : `cout << f2 << endl;
But i am getting following build erros while compilation:
Error   C2805   binary 'operator <<' has too few parameters
fr: undeclared identifier
left of get_num must be struct/union/class

Comment: Is that the only error you get? Nothing about `Fraction` being undeclared when you define the `operator<<` function? You do know that in C++ you must declare symbols before you use them?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23335209/error-overloaded-operator-must-be-a-binary-operator-has-3-parameters

Comment: you should also take `Fraction` by const reference

Comment: @DROY: thanks .. will check stack overflow other threads before posting :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the order of your code like this:

```
class Fraction
{
private:
    int num, den;
public:
int get_num()
    {
        return num;
    }
    int get_den()
    {
        return den;
    }
};

ostream & operator<<(ostream & os, Fraction & fr)
{
    return os << fr.get_num() << '/' << fr.get_den();
}
```