# C++: Operator overloading- cout and cin -- ostream function, cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function

Tags: c++

I overloaded a cout and cin opeartor and when I tried to use it, it gave me an error like this:

```
1 IntelliSense: function "std::basic_ostream<_Elem, _Traits>::basic_ostream(const     std::basic_ostream<_Elem, _Traits>::_Myt &) 
[with _Elem=char, _Traits=std::char_traits<char>]" 
(declared at line 84 of "C:\Program   Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\ostream") cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function
```

And here's the header file of my class:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>

class Point2D
{
private:
    int m_X;
    int m_Y;
public:
    Point2D(): m_X(0), m_Y(0)
    {
    }

    Point2D(int x, int y): m_X(x), m_Y(y)
    {
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream out, const Point2D &point)
    {
        out << "(" << point.m_X << "," << point.m_Y << ")" << std::endl;

        return out;
    }

    friend std::istream& operator>> (std::istream in, Point2D &point) 
    {
        in >> point.m_X;
        in >> point.m_Y;

        return in;
    }

    int getX() const { return m_X; }
    int getY() const { return m_Y; }

    ~Point2D();
};
```

So, basically, it's just a class that can return and set X and Y coordinates. And I overwrote `<<` and `>>` operators to make things easier.

But when I try to use it in the main function like this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include <iostream>
#include "Point2D.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    Point2D point(7, 7);

    cout << point;  //there's an error here.


    return 0;
}
```

There seems to be the error on this line:

```
cout << point;
```

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: Those classes are not copyable. See [operator overloading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading) for how to properly overload these operators.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message says `ostream` cannot be copied.

```
friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream out, const Point2D &point)
{
    ...
```

`std::ostream out` is *pass-by-value*: When the `operator <<` is called, compiler tries to *copy* the argument. However, `std::ostream` cannot be copied, so compilation is failed.

You should use *reference*.

```
friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &out, const Point2D &point)
{
    ...

friend std::istream& operator>> (std::istream &in, Point2D &point) 
{
    ...
```

(Even if you're using some classes which provides copying, you shouldn't usually use pass-by-val. Copying some objects is so expensive;)

Comment: @James If my answer is helpful for you, plz choose it >o<

Answer (score 3):

Just had the same problem. For other peoples looking for a solution. The error

```
function "std::basic_ostream<_Elem, _Traits>::basic_ostream(const std::basic_ostream<_Elem, _Traits> &) [with _Elem=char, _Traits=std::char_traits<char>]" (declared at line 83 of "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\include\ostream") cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function
```

comes from the line:

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream os, const Point2D &point)
```

correct it to this and it should be fine:

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &os, const Point2D &point)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is with the arguments

```
friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream out, const Point2D &point)
```

The input argument `out` is pass-by-value. When the compiler tries to copy the `std::ostream` variable by value it fails and thus the error. Pass the variable `out` by reference as shown below and it should clear the error. Also, the return type is pass-by-reference, so by doing the below change your are returning the same object and not creating a new copy.

```
friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &out, const Point2D &point)
```

Useful link: [How to properly overload the << operator for an ostream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476272/how-to-properly-overload-the-operator-for-an-ostream)