# Why does overloading ostream's operator<< need a reference "&"?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I've been learning C++.

[From this page,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476272/how-to-properly-overload-the-operator-for-an-ostream) I understood that overloading "<<" operator of ostream can be done in this way.

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Objects& obj) {
    //
    return out;
} 
//Implementation
```

and

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Object& obj);
//In the corresponding header file
```

My question is... why does this function need "&" at the end of `ostream` and `Object`?

At least I know that "&" is used to...

1. Take the address of a value
2. Declare a reference to a type

However, I think neither of them applies to the overloading described above. I've spent a lot of time in googling and reading a text book, but I can't find the answer.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Passing the object by reference is to prevent copying it while ensuring the object reference is always valid (comparing to pointer).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> why does this function need "&" at the end of ostream and Object?

Because you are passing them by reference.
Why are you passing them by reference. To prevent a copy.

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Objects const& obj)
                             //           ^^^^^       note the const
                             //                       we don't need to modify
                             //                       the obj while printing.
```

The `obj` can be copied (potentially). But what if it is expensive to copy. So best to pass it by reference to prevent an unnecessary copy.

The `out` is of type `std::ostream`. This can not be copied (the copy constructor is disabled). So you need to pass by reference.

I normally declare the stream operator direcctly in the class declaration:

```
class X
{
    std::string    name;
    int            age;

    void swap(X& other) noexcept
    {
        std::swap(name, other.name);
        std::swap(age,  other.age);
    }
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& str, X const& data)
    {
        return str << data.name << "\n" << age << "\n";
    }
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& str, X& data)
    {
        X alt;
        // Read into a temporary incase the read fails.
        // This makes sure the original is unchanged on a fail
        if (std::getline(str, alt.name) && str >> alt.age)
        {
            // The read worked.
            // Get rid of the trailing new line.
            // Then swap the alt into the real object.
            std::string ignore;
            std::getline(str, ignore);
            data.swap(alt);
        }
        return str;
    }
};
```

Comment: Best answer. +1 for the detailed explanation.

Comment: More to the point, you wouldn't _want_ the stream to be copied even if doing so made any technical sense.

Answer (score 0):

Example

```
void f(int& index)
{
    index = 3;
}
```

means `f` is a function with an `int` parameter that is passed by reference. So after

```
int a = 4;
f(a);
```

`a` has a value of `3`. For the operator you mentioned this means that the `ostream` as well as `Object` may be changed during the execution of the operator (as some kind of function).