# Structure and template class in C++

Tags: c++, list, templates

My task is to create a priority queue template class and show its work using different data types: int, string and any struct. I have to add, delete, print a specific element.

The class is:

```
template< class Type >
class PriorityList
{
    private:
    List<Type> elems;
```

As a struct I picked was this:

```
struct SOMESTRUCT
{
    int num;
    char word[];
};
```

As I understand a template class is a universal class which can be used for any incoming data type. I can see how to create the class for int and char [], but how do I make it work for struct too? Since you can't just write cout<< struct, neither cin>>... I'd have to create another function for inputting/outputting my struct, but if I put it in my template class, the class wouldn't be universal again.

What do I do?  Also, do I have to make template  or leave just one typename?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly overload the << operator for an ostream?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476272/how-to-properly-overload-the-operator-for-an-ostream)

Comment: [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1z2f6c2k.aspx) might also help.

Comment: Hmm.. thank you for the option! But then I should also create my own Int and Char classes, right?  So I can then write template <class C>, right?

Comment: @Mary ... what?

Comment: Please post the full program.

Comment: @melpomene To make the template class universal, I have to make my own Int and Char too, right?

Comment: @flatmouse Unfortunately, there's nothing to post yet.

Comment: @Mary No, why do you think so?

Comment: Write a first program only with `int`. Then convert it to a template, then deal with the `struct`. If you're asking for a full template to be written for you in an answer then the question is too broad at this stage.

Comment: <class ...> is just a keyword. It accepts any type. PriorityList<int> should just work.

Comment: @flatmouse Nope, I'm not. I was just struggling with template<...> thing. Okay, I'll try that, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
template<typename C>
class PriorityList
{
// ...
};
```

for any type C, including `int`, `char`, `SOMESTRUCT`. I would recommend against using cin and cout in your template, since it makes it harder to use for any class. You would need to [overload operator<< and operator>>](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/input_output_operators_overloading.htm) for each class you use, which might be tricky.

Instead you should just define some simple member functions. I would try to copy the style of [`std::queue<T>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/queue/), since people will be familiar with it.

For example:

```
template<typename C>
class PriorityQueue
{
    public: 
    void push(const C& item, int priority=0){
    // ...
    }
    C& front(){
    // ...
    }
    // and other required functions
};
```

Once it is defined, you can test it for different classes however you want. You can e.g. create a `main()` to declare a `PriorityQueue<int>`, read some `int`s from `std::cin` and then call those functions you defined, or you can just declare some instances of `SOMESTRUCT` and pass them into a `PriorityQueue<SOMESTRUCT>`.

In a real-life project you would probably use a proper unit testing framework such as [catch](https://github.com/philsquared/Catch) for this purpose, which would automatically check everything works.