# trying to print set by algorithm

Tags: c++

I have some problem inside my project:
I have a class named Item that represents item inside a store, it has three attitudes like string of name and it's cost. in the main program I'm using set of items (`set<Item>`) and the problem is when I'm trying to print the set using the copy algorithm:

`copy(items.begin(), items.end(), ostream_iterator<Item>(cout, " ## "));`
the problem is that the compiler sends me this error:

Error   1   error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const Item' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

I really don't know why its happen to me, help please ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/476272/how-to-properly-overload-the-operator-for-an-ostream

Comment: Show a [mcve], please. In particular, do you actually have a suitable streaming operator defined for your class?

Comment: Did you overload the `std::ostream& operator << (...)` for your `Item` class?.. The error you are seeing is even quite informative compared with what we saw with older compilers years ago.

Comment: should I ? @WhiZTiM

Comment: @DRJ, No, the compiler's AI will overload it for you:-).. Ok, quips aside. . .  Yes, you should overload it, Read the [Operator Overloading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading?rq=1) on Stackoverflow. Also you may want check out some really [good C++ resources](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) curated by the C++ community here.