# Print Operator overload fail?

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading

Am practicing C++ basic inheritance concepts, came across the need to print out a custom class object and wrote an overload, followed guide exactly yet still does not register use of the new operator for printing (<<).

Am wondering if typed incorrectly or had some declaration/initiation errors somewhere else?

> no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are
>   ‘std::basic_ostream’ and ‘Choco’)  std::cout<< "Choco value: "
>   << child << endl;

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Sweets {
        public:
                // pure virtual, child MUST implement or become abstract
                // Enclosing class becomes automatically abstract - CANNOT instantiate
                virtual bool eat() = 0;
};

// public inheritance : public -> public, protected -> protected, private only accessible thru pub/pro members
class Choco : public Sweets {
        public:

                bool full;

                Choco() {
                        full = false;
                }

                // Must implement ALL inherited pure virtual
                bool eat() {
                        full = true;
                }

                // Overload print operator
                bool operator<<(const Choco& c) {
                        return this->full;
                }
};

int main() {

// Base class object
//sweets parent;
Choco child;

// Base class Ptr
// Ptr value = address of another variable
Sweets* ptr; // pointer to sweets
ptr = &child;

std::cout<< "Sweets* value:  " << ptr << endl;
std::cout<< "Choco address: " << &child << endl;
std::cout<< "Choco value: " << child << endl; // Printing causes error!
}
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4421706/1896169

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476272/how-to-properly-overload-the-operator-for-an-ostream

Comment: @jamarcus_13  This operator  bool operator<<(const Choco& c) {

                        return this->full;

                }
 does not make sense at least because the parameter c is not used.:)

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but the logic of this class is inside-out. If a person eats the chocolate, it's the **person** who becomes full, not the **chocolate**.

Answer (score 0):

The operator is defined the following way outside the class because it is not a class member.

```
std::ostream & operator <<( std::ostream &os, const Choco &c ) 
{
    return os << c.full;
}
```

Take into account that the function

```
bool eat() {
    full = true;
}
```

shall have a return statement with an expression of the type `bool` or it should be declared with the return type `void` in the base and derived classes.