# How to custom ostream c++

Tags: c++, stream, ostream

i have a class:

```
class Y{
   public:
       int x;
       Y();
};
```

Main:

```
int main(){
    Y y;
    y.x = 10;
    y << mystream;

    return 0;
}
```

I just wanna to cause any action when `y<<mystream` is typed.
I tried in my class header like those:

```
friend Y mystream(Y y);
friend ostream mystream(ostream o, Y y)
```

And etc. but nothing didn't work. Any ideas to custom this stream?

Best regards!

Comment: You'll need to overload the << operator.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476272/how-to-properly-overload-the-operator-for-an-ostream

Comment: The code doesn't compile. You cannot private members.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to properly overload the << operator for an ostream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476272/how-to-properly-overload-the-operator-for-an-ostream)

Comment: Why `y << stream` instead of `stream << y`, since the latter is how the `<<` operator is usually invoked on a stream.

Answer (score 1):

You can overload the insertion operator "<<" to take a `class A` object as its `LHS` and an ostream object as its `rhs`:

```
class A{
    public:
        int x;

        friend ostream& operator << (A& lhs, ostream& out){
            out << lhs.x;
            return out;
        }
};



int main(){

    A a;
    a.x = 7;
    a << cout; // 7

    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `<<` operator should take the `ostream&` as its first parameter, not the second, so you can do `cout << a << endl`.   Writing it so you do `a << cout` is wrong.

Comment: ok, I see the OP wrote it that way, so downvote reversed, but the point still remains

Comment: @Alnitak: I know but this is what the OP wanted.

Comment: @Alnitak: what is really wrong? In my class I am free to reverse the parameters. But I know it is something we are not used to. Especially when writing: `myClassOblj << cout << anotherValue << endl;` Yes it's unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

You have to overload the '<<' operator in the class then you can use it for custom output stream. Also when passing the **object of ostream**, make sure  that they are **passed by reference**. You can refer to this site for example http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overloading-stream-insertion-operators-c/

Answer (score 0):

I dont't need:

`A a;
cout<<a;
// or
a<<cout;`

For example I can do this for cout in main:

```
    ostream& cause(ostream& out)
    {
    out<<"My stream is here";
    return out;
    }

    int main()
    {
    cout<<cause; // Print here 'my stream is here'
return 0;
    }
```

I just wanna get this behaviour for my class instead of std::cout, so i wanna write in main:

`A a;
a<<cause; // i want to manipulate stream(?)`