# Best practices accessing members in function with const reference parameter in C++

Tags: c++, reference, parameter-passing, constants

What is the best practice to implement following scenario:
`Class A` holds a member object of Type `B`.

```
class A
{
private:
  B b;
};

class B
{
private:
  int x;
};
```

A print function which gets an object of type `A` as `const &` parameter, should print the members of `a`and `b` :

```
void Print(const A& a)
{
  cout << a.b.x;
}
```

A read function should set the values of `a` (and `b`) and their members:

```
void Read(A& a)
{ 
  // ...
  a.b.x = 2;
}
```

How should `class A` be implement regarding its member access?

- Should "`b`" be public?
- Should "`class A`" provide 2 getters for b (1 for write and 1 read access to "b")?

**Additional information:**
In my real system the classes `A` and `B` are much larger and they are part of  a huge legacy system. In this legacy system `Print` and `Read` are member functions of a "View-Model", where `Print` writes the values to the GUI and `Read` reads the values from the GUI and sets the members of `A` and `B`. So the resposibility of `A` and `B` is to hold the data (some kind of data models).

Comment: Why not shift the responsibility of reading and writing to `B`, or another overloads of `Print` and `Read` in this case? Still, you need to make those functions member or `friend`.

Comment: I especially like how the `Read` function actually writes. Keep them guessing and on their toes.

Answer (score 4):

You ought to use member functions instead, and keep the data as encapsulated as possible. To that end, `Print` could be a member function of `A`:

```
class A
{
    B b;
public:
    void Print() const /*Let's add some const correctness*/
    {
        b.Print();
    }
};
```

and

```
class B
{
    int x;
public:
    void Print() const
    {
        std::cout << x;
    }

    B& operator=(int new_x) /*Standard form of the assignment operator*/
    {
        x = new_x;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Note that I've provided an *assigment operator* for `B`. You could then build a function in class `A`:

```
void setX(int x)
{
    b = x;
}
```

Finally though, for your printing, the idiomatic way is to overload `<<` for `std::ostream`. Then you can remove your `Print` functions. See [How to properly overload the << operator for an ostream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476272/how-to-properly-overload-the-operator-for-an-ostream).