# Overloading the stream insertion operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operator-keyword, cout

I am trying to overload the stream insertion operator for an assignment.  In my header file, I have the following:

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream, Vector);
```

In my implementation file, I have:

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& outputStream, Vector& displayMe) {
    outputStream << "<" << displayMe.GetVX << "," << displayMe.GetVY << ">";
    return outputStream;
}
```

I am getting an error that says:

"invalid specifier outside a class declaration"

The error is pointing to the line that begins with friend ostream& in my implementation file.

I am new to operator overloading obviously.  Am I supposed to define this outside of the class?  I am just confused about why I am getting this error and how I go about fixing my code.  Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476272/how-to-properly-overload-the-operator-for-an-ostream)

Comment: You can't use `friend` outside of a class declaration. Also, your definition in your implementation file does not match your declaration in your header file (`ostream` vs `ostream&` in the 1st parameter, and `Vector` vs `Vector&` in the 2nd parameter). The declaration and definition need to match each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare the `ostream<<` operator within the `Vector` class:

```
class Vector
{
  // ...
  friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, Vector&);
};
```

Notice also that you need to use references in the signature as well.

You don't specify `friend` in the implementation of the operator.

Also, it's advisable to take the `Vector` by const-reference here:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream&, Vector const&);
```