# Undeclared identifier when overloading operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, undeclared-identifier

When trying to attempt to overload `operator<<` in my `shape.cpp`, it can't seem to recognize the variables within the class, even though it is a `friend` of the class.

My `.cpp` file:

```
#include "Shape.h"

ostream& operator << (ostream& cout, const Shape& shapes)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++) //points is undefined
    {
        cout << points[i] << endl; 
    }
}
```

My `.h` file:

```
#include <vector>
#include "Point.h"
#pragma once

using namespace std;

class Shape
{
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& cout, const Shape& shapes);

    private:
        vector <Point> points; //Ordered list of vertices
};
```

I already used the same overload for my `point` class and it worked fine.

Comment: `cout` is a bad name for a parameter, especially with `using namespace std;`. You need `shapes.points` since the function is not a member of the class.

Comment: Did you mean `shapes.points`?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476272/how-to-properly-overload-the-operator-for-an-ostream/35811860#35811860 eg https://godbolt.org/z/fabefxTGv

Comment: If you use the same overload for the point class and it worked fine, that means you did something different.   Your code, as posted, has multiple problems - and the undeclared identifier is the most benign concern (since it triggered a diagnostic).   The worse problem, if you fixed that, will be undefined behaviour that will probably not be diagnosed at all, but can unpredictably cause a runtime error.   And there is plenty of information online about why `using namespace std` is BAD PRACTICE in a header file.

Answer (score 1):

A `friend` function is not a class member. It can be treated as any other non-class function. Except that, because it's a `friend`, it has access to its private members:

```
ostream& operator << (ostream& cout, const Shape& shapes)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < shapes.points.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << shapes.points[i] << endl; 
    }
}
```

It should now be clear that the object gets passed in as the `shapes` parameter. Well, it's `points` member must, therefore, be `shapes.points`.

However, we can do even better than that. How about using range iteration?

```
ostream& operator << (ostream& cout, const Shape& shapes)
{
    for (auto &v:shapes.points)
    {
        cout << v << endl; 
    }
}
```

Comment: The operator is also missing a return statement.